# git remote rm not allowing me to remove config section?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, git-remote

So, this is my first time making a website, using git, and the such.

i was trying to use git as a way of updating my website. i was told to do the following:

```
git remote add live ssh://user@domain.com/absolute-path-to-site
```

followed by:

```
git push live master
```

when i tried pushing i got the following message:

> fatal: '/absolute-path-to-site' does not appear to be a git
>   repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

i figured i did something wrong and tried backtracking by using

```
git remote rm ssh://user@domain.com/absolute-path-to-site
```

well it doesn't let me remove the path, I get:

> error: Could not remove config section 'remote.ssh://user@domain.com/absolute-path-to-site'

I can't really find anything to help my with this situation (or I'm not looking right) please help.

Comment: Your website needs to be initialized as a git repository and have .git folders etc.  So ideally you want to do a git init on the web server file-system, copy your files there and commit, then clone your website to your development location and then you will be able to treat the website as a remote.

Comment: I migrated all of the files from the local version of my website to the live site, including the .git directory, does that count as initialized or should i do it again? thank you so much for the help.

Comment: For the rm part that's not working you want to specify the name of the remote, thus live.  The correct syntax would be **git remote remove live**

Comment: Can you manually ssh to that location and make sure that the path is accessible to that user?

Comment: when i try to use **git remote remove live** i get `usage: git remote remove <name> `.

as for manually ssh to the location, I can do that it is accessible. I believe my problem is that i stopped at /destination instead of /destination/.git . could that be the problem?

Comment: What do you get when you run **git remote -vv**.  I will need to reproduce your setup to confirm if it will work or not.

Comment: live ssh://username@fireplug.dreamhost.com/dev.website.com/wp-content/themes/astrid (fetch)
live ssh://username@fireplug.dreamhost.com/dev.website.com/wp-content/themes/astrid (push)

Comment: Ok, that looks good.

Comment: Is there anything I should do?

Comment: Can you check when you ssh manually if you can change into the .git folder and view a file?

Comment: I can go in and go into files without a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove the remote manually in `.git/config`, remove the part like this:

```
[remote "live"]
    url = ssh://username@fireplug.dreamhost.com/dev.website.com/wp-content/themes/astrid
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/live/*
```

Then save the config file, and use `git remote -v` to double check if it removed or not.

Answer (score 1):

The correct [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)  command was:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote remove live
```

Directly editing a `.git/config` file is not recommended.

Comment: @bruno-melofiro I believe this answer should be marked as correct... as @VonC stated, it's not good practice to make edits directly to the `.git/config` file.